# Can't find the role I just created in Discord.py - Why?

Tags: python, discord.py

When I create a role, try to find it by name, store in a variable `role` and change the role's place in the roles hierarchy, it appears that the variable has the value of `None`. That means it didn't find the role in the guild, right? But I just created the role! Why is it happening?

```
await guild.create_role(name="Muted", colour=discord.Colour.red(), permissions=discord.Permissions(send_messages=False))
role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")
await role.edit(position=3)
```

An error appears:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'edit'
```

Comment: The `create_role` coroutine returns the newly created role. Have you tried `role = await guild.create_role(...)` instead of `discord.utils.get`?

Comment: Yes, that worked, thank you, Wander Nauta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save it into a variable from the beginning, this can also be done for any object (TextChannel, Message, etc..)

```py
role = await guild.create_role(name="Muted",
                               colour=discord.Colour.red(),
                               permissions=discord.Permissions(send_messages=False))
await role.edit(position=3)
```

Comment: Well, ok, looks like it works. But why wasn't it working with the code as in my post?